# How to create a query that is able to sort data into 2 groups?

Tags: ms-access

so I'm very new to Access - just started learning it this week. I have data comprised of a bunch of policy numbers with corresponding ratings and premium values.

What I'm trying to do is create a query table that aggregates this data by rating (=1 or >1), this is the part I can't figure out. In design mode, I have put criteria =1 or >1, but it's not doing anything; when I switch to datasheet view, it just lists all of the ratings instead of two boxes that say =1 and >1. If anyone could give me insight on how to do this, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: What field are you applying this =1 or >1 criteria to? Edit question to show query SQL and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand after reading your question, you want a query that shows two columns, one that counts the records with a rating of 1 and one that counts the records with a rating of greater than 1.

The best way to do this is to set up two expression columns, both wrapped in a `count` as you can see below:

```
SELECT Count(IIf([Rating]=1,[Rating],Null)) AS [=1], Count(IIf([Rating]>1,[Rating],Null)) AS [>1]
FROM tblSortRating;
```

[image: Query Design View]

[image: Query Datasheet View]

If you have any questions or I've misunderstood your question leave a comment and I'll get back to you.